# How can I print out session message in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to print out my session/flash message to my user(s) as feedback.

I couldn't get it to display, worse than that, it give me the error.

[image]

---

## view

```
{{-- Flash Message --}}
@if($success_register)
@if ($message = Session::get('success_register'))
<div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
  <i class=" fa fa-check cool-green "></i>
  {{ nl2br($message) }}
</div>
@endif
@endif
```

---

## controller

```
return Redirect::to('/')
    ->with('success_register',' Your Account has been created ! <small> Email has been sent to set-password, and activation.</small>');
```

---

- What did I do wrong here ?
- Is there a better way to print them out ?
- Can someone please correct me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Session::get('success_register') on both occassions simply said!

```
@if(Session::has('success_register'))
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
        <i class=" fa fa-check cool-green "></i>
        {{ nl2br(Session::get('success_register')) }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: So how to I fix that in my view ? Can you please include that as part of your answer ?